# regex for dot language identifier

Tags: java, regex, groovy, dot

[The dot language](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) has a few rules for an identifier. I would like to make a regex that meets the first one in groovy. The rule is

Any string of alphabetic (`[a-zA-Z\200-\377]`) characters, underscores ('`_`') or digits (`[0-9]`), not beginning with a digit;

I wanted to do something like this

```
[_a-zA-Z\200-\377][_0-9a-zA-Z\200-\377]*
```

but groovy complains about the \200-\377. How can I make this regex groovy compatible?

**Edit**: some additional code

```
String getId(String id) {
    if(id ==~ /[_a-zA-Z\200-\377][_0-9a-zA-Z\200-\377]*/) {
        return id
    } else {
        return "\"$id\""
    }
}
```

and the error

```
Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 9
[_a-zA-Z\200-\377][_0-9a-zA-Z\200-\377]*
```

**Edit 2**: this is the spock test

```
@Unroll('"#id" converts to "#expected"')
def 'ids are converted to dot ids'() {
    expect:
    graphviz.getId(id) == expected

    where:
    id          | expected
    '_'         | '_'
    'a'         | 'a'
    'A'         | 'A'
    'a9'        | 'a9'
    ' '         | '" "'
    '234'       | '"234"'
    'two words' | '"two words"'
}
```

Comment: I believe groovy is relying on Java's regex for its regex support . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html  So have you tried `\0200-\0377`? (I guess `\200-\377` is octal value, as in C/C++ ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with Groovy 2.4.9:

```
def regex = "[_a-zA-Z\200-\377][_0-9a-zA-Z\200-\377]*"

assert '_aB' ==~ regex
assert '_123AB' ==~ regex

assert 246 == (('ö' as char) as int) 
assert 252 == (('ü' as char) as int) 
assert '_aMötleyCrüe123' ==~ regex
```

Comment: I updated the question with more info. When I switched from the slashy string to a normal string it worked. Thanks for the help.